# CSS Pseudo Element inside another style block

Tags: css, pseudo-element

Structural question.

I am trying to put the pseudo element inside of the a tag css bracket. 
Currently it looks like this:

```
    a {
        background-color: grey;
        padding: 50px 100px 50px 100px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 50px;
        border: 3px solid grey;
        border-radius: 25px;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 10px #080808, 0px 0px 25px 30px #2f4f4finset;
        text-shadow: 3px 3px #999999;
        margin-left: 10%;
        margin-top: 20%;
    }

    a:before {
    content: "* ";
}

    a:after {
   content: " *";
}
```

I would like it to work like this:

```
    a {
        background-color: grey;
        padding: 50px 100px 50px 100px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 50px;
        border: 3px solid grey;
        border-radius: 25px;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 10px #080808, 0px 0px 25px 30px #2f4f4finset;
        text-shadow: 3px 3px #999999;
        margin-left: 10%;
        margin-top: 20%;

    a:before {
    content: "* ";
}

    a:after {
   content: " *";
}
    }
```

Any tips on how to properly 'call' the pseudo elements without breaking out of the original a tag styling?

Comment: There is no nesting in CSS. The "proper" way to do it, as you ask, is as you've shown in your first code sample.

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved with a preprocessor such as [SASS](http://sass-lang.com) or [LESS](http://lesscss.org).

```
a {
    // styles here
    &:before {
        // styles for :before
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that in pure CSS because pure CSS doesn't allow for nested style blocks. You'd need a preprocessor like [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) or [LESS](http://lesscss.org/).